# Python: concatenate arrays stored in a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large dictionary which stores following arrays:

```
Store = dict()
Store['A'] = A #size 500x30
Store['B'] = B #size 500x20
```

I am having only A and B for illustration. In my current real life situation I have about 500 keys and values in the dictionary I am using.

I want to concatenate the arrays in an elegant way to get an array C.

For illustration this is what I aim to achieve:

```
A = np.random.normal( 0, 1, ( 500, 20 ) )
B = np.random.normal( 0, 1, ( 500, 30 ) )
C = np.concatenate((A,B),1)
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: You seem to know how to concatenate arrays. Do you not know how to retrieve them from the dictionary? Or do you not know how to put those steps together? This seems straightforward.

Comment: well, does the order matter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the order does not matter, pass the values of your dictionary to `numpy.concatenate`:

```
>>> store = {'A':np.array([1,2,3]), 'B':np.array([3,4,5])}
>>> np.concatenate(store.values(),1)
array([1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5])
```

If the order does matter, you can use

```
np.concatenate([v for k,v in sorted(store.items(), key=...)], 1)
```

Pass in any key function you like, or just leave the key argument out if you want to sort lexicographically. Sadly, `concatenate` does not seem to take a generator object.

Comment: I found this only works after wrapping `store.values()` in `list()` and setting `axis = 0`:

`np.concatenate(list(store.values()),0)`

This question/answer is very old though so likely numpy has changed rather than original answer being wrong. Just wanted to help any new visitors.

Answer (score 7):

`np.concatenate([Store[x] for x in Store], 1)`

`np.concatenate([Store[x] for x in sorted(Store)], 1)` if order matters.

Comment: This won't work if order matters, which seems likely.

Comment: Edited to take that into account. But why using a dict in the first place if order matters. Any other transformation of `Store.keys()` will also do.